# Optimized Solution For Traversing List of Objects and Each Object has List of Object

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, object-oriented-analysis, code-complexity

I need optimized solution to one the problem I came across:

There is an Object A that has some fields :

```
class A{
    String city;
    String state;
    String phoneNo;
    // other fields
}
```

There is another list of objects Bi.e:

```
class B{
    String name;
    int id;
    List<C> Objects;
}

Class C{
    // having similar member variable as in A
    String city;
    String state;
    String phone;
    // other fields
}
```

Now, the problem is I want to iterate over List of Object B and fetch list of object C and compare those details with object A.

Basic O(n^2) solution to my mind is:

```
for(B b : bs){
   List<C> objects= b.getObjects()
   for(C c : objects){
      if(c.getState.equalsIgnoreCase(A.getState)){
      }
      .... similar condition to apply ...
   }
}
```

At the end I need all the List of B object having matced with A member variable and I want to reduce complexity mainly both time and space.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class C extends class A, for starters.

```
class A {
    String city;
    String state;
    String phone;
    // other fields of class A

    boolean customEquals(A other) {
        // here you can compare fields specific for class A
    }
}

class C extends A {
    // fields specific for class C
}
```

And then use `customEquals` method while comparing the objects in loop:

```
for (B b : bs) {
    List<C> cs = b.getCs();
    for (C c : cs) {
        if(a.customEquals(c)) {
            // here you have your b object you are looking for
            // further loop iterations can be ommitted at this point
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response , but in your solution correct me If I am wrong there would be two loops again:  class A {
    String city;
    String state;
    String phone;
    // other fields of class A

    boolean customEquals(A other) {
        // here you can compare fields specific for class A
    }
}

class C extends A {
    // fields specific for class C
}
A a = new A();
for(B b : List of b){
 List<C> objects = b.getObjects();
 for(C c : objects){{
  if(a.customEquals(c)){
    -- some logic
  }
 }
}   Can we reduce it to further

Comment: Yeah, but there is nothing wrong with it - it is not really O(n^2)... On the other hand, you can iterate over b objects and extract all the c objects to one collection, and then iterate over c objects collection, but the complexity stays the same. There is no need (or even no way) to reduce it further - you have to access every c object at least once.

Comment: Yeah , but the requirement is if there is matching C object with A . I need B object at the end. C object is just for matching purpose.

Comment: So when a is matched with c you can return b object - simple as that.